# Python - save different sheets of an excel file as individual excel files

Tags: python, xlrd, excel-automation

Newbie : I have an Excel file, which has more than 100 different Sheets. Each sheet contains several tables and charts.

I wish to save every sheet as a new Excel file.

I tried many python codes, but none of them worked.

Kindly help in this. Thanks!

Edit 1 : In reponse to comments, this is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

inputFile = 'D:\Excel\Complete_data.xlsx'

#getting sheet names
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(inputFile, on_demand=True)
sheet_names = xls.sheet_names()

path = "D:/Excel/All Files/"

#create a new excel file for every sheet
for name in sheet_names:
        parsing = pd.ExcelFile(inputFile).parse(sheetname = name)

        #writing data to the new excel file
        parsing.to_excel(path+str(name)+".xlsx", index=False)
```

To be precise, the problem is coming in copying tables and charts.

Comment: Can you include to your question what you tried, and what did not work for you?

Comment: I am a newbie and just tried basic parsing using XLRD module. I was not able to get any table or chart in the new Excel files.

Comment: @raderick added my code

Answer (score 9):

I have just worked through this issue so will post my solution, I do not know how it will affect charts etc.

```
import os
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlwt

path = #place path where files to split up are
targetdir = (path + "New_Files/") #where you want your new files

if not os.path.exists(targetdir): #makes your new directory
    os.makedirs(targetdir)

for root,dir,files in os.walk(path, topdown=False): #all the files you want to split
    xlsfiles=[f for f in files] #can add selection condition here

for f in xlsfiles:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root, f), on_demand=True)
    for sheet in wb.sheets(): #cycles through each sheet in each workbook
        newwb = copy(wb) #makes a temp copy of that book
        newwb._Workbook__worksheets = [ worksheet for worksheet in newwb._Workbook__worksheets if worksheet.name == sheet.name ]
        #brute force, but strips away all other sheets apart from the sheet being looked at
        newwb.save(targetdir + f.strip(".xls") + sheet.name + ".xls") 
        #saves each sheet as the original file name plus the sheet name
```

Not particularly elegant but worked well for me and gives easy functionality. Hopefully useful for someone.