# How to split several XLSX files, that contain several sheets, into separate XLSX files?

Tags: python, python-3.6, glob

I'm trying to speed up this script to read 95+ xlsx files and split out th files that contain multiple sheets into individual xlsx files. Right now, the script is crawling. Is there any way to speed it up?

```
import glob


listOfFiles = glob.glob('/path/*.xlsx')
for doc in listOfFiles:
    wb = load_workbook(filename=(doc))

    for sheet in wb.worksheets[1:]:
        new_wb = Workbook()
        ws = new_wb.active
        for row_data in sheet.iter_rows():
            for row_cell in row_data:
                ws[row_cell.coordinate].value = row_cell.value

        new_wb.save('/newpath/{0}.xlsx'.format(sheet.title))
```

Comment: Have you tried this method to see if it is faster? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416410/python-save-different-sheets-of-an-excel-file-as-individual-excel-files

Comment: I just tested that script.  In my scenario, it worked super, super fast!!  Very nice!!